# Corrupted Hard Drive or OS? How to recover my files?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

To start with, I'm not completely new to Linux, but there are a lot of things I haven't had to deal with before. I've been using Kubuntu for a little over a year now, but that's about it.

Last night I kept getting errors about not being able to write to my home directory. I wish I'd written them down now. I hadn't gotten these errors before, but I'd gotten others that restarting usually fixed the problem. When it loads back up, it gets into BusyBox. Same for recovery mode. So I `fsck /dev/sda2`, and I get

```
Inodes were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
```

I select to fix them, and it goes through that. Then I get

```
Error reading block 9970356 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while reading directory block. Ignore error<y>?
```

Now I've been getting this seemingly endless stream of these. I'm hoping by the end of it I could boot into Linux and salvage anything I hadn't saved to my external. I don't know what could have gone wrong in the first place, or how to find what may have happened. The last thing I did before I started having problems was attempt to install Twitch to Wine. Would I be able to slave this drive to another computer and recover my information? (I did not do an encrypted LVM or encrypt my home folder)

Answer (score 0):

I've had pretty good luck with `ddrescue` in the past, though it can take quite a long time to run (possibly a few days, depending on the size of the disk and how many errors it encounters). It's better to abort your current `fsck` and avoid doing any more damage to the disk. Use `ddrescue` to copy it over somewhere else, and then run `fsck` against that copy, and you'll probably have better luck.